# Excess elements in scalar initializer in byte create in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, byte

In my project, I create a byte:

```
Byte bytes = {0x7E, 0x7F};
```

But there comes a warning:

> Excess elements in scalar initializer

What this mean? does it effect me?

Comment: just see my ans its a memory access issue  ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to create single dimensional array where you are not declaring size of it there's no memory set aside for an array so that's why the compiler is generating a warning which may cause an runtime error ahead.

Set array size:

```
// single dimen
Byte bytes[2] = {0x7E, 0x7F};

// double dimen
Byte bytes[1][2] = {{0x7E, 0x7F}, {0x7E, 0x7F}};
```

Answer (score 0):

how stupid! I create a byte array should be like this:

`Byte bytes[] = {0x7E, 0x7F}`

I did not write the `[]`.